# How does a Bluetooth beacon work with an app?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

Does a Bluetooth beacon work like this, it transmits ID’s and a phone with BLE detects the ID and sends it to a app looking for ID's which does something if the ID matches one in a database for example

Question:
Can you connect the Bluetooth beacon to a app and customize what ID is being transmitted like the boss logs in the app and the beacon starts transmitting an ID depending on the time.

The worker logs in the app and it will start listening for ID's and update a database depending on what ID it has received?

Is there handshake that needs to happen for an android app to detect ID’s being transmitted by a beacon or it can receive ID’s from any beacon?

Comment: Do you read [this](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-04-14-building-android-beacon-android-ibeacon-tutorial-overview/) tutorial?

Comment: @AndriyOmelchenko nice one ;)

Comment: Nope but will do now thanks, iv been mainly going over the blog on pointrlabs on beacons and a journal on beacon usage to try get a basic development idea on how it would work/initial research as i have no experience with beacons or the android studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Can you connect the Bluetooth beacon to a app and customize what ID is being transmitted like the boss logs in the app and the beacon starts transmitting an ID depending on the time.***

No, if you want to modify the broadcasted UUID, you have to do that on the firmware of the beacon itself, not from an app.

***The worker logs in the app and it will start listening for ID's and update a database depending on what ID it has received?***

Yes, this is very possible. In Android you can use `AltBeacon` and scan for beacons in your region, and based on the major/minor values you can update your database accordingly.

***Is there handshake that needs to happen for an android app to detect ID’s being transmitted by a beacon or it can receive ID’s from any beacon?***

No, there is no handshake needed. Once a Bluetooth signal starts broadcasting, as long as it is at a detectable frequency, your mobile device will be able to pick up the signal as well as the identifiers.

**Note:** Consider looking into https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/, it will clear up many of your implementation questions.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot i understand where i went wrong, so instead i could customize the major and minor id's within my own app to let the user app know what to update? for example from 2pm to 3pm the beacon transmits a different major and minor id and at 4 to 6pm its a different major and minor id.

Comment: You can't easily change a hardware beacon's transmission identifiers based on the time.  But you can easily do this with a software beacon (using and Android or other device as the transmitter).  The Android Beacon Library linked above lets you transmit, too.

Comment: Sorry for the questions, I realized I was approaching the problem in the wrong way. I will just leave the beacon alone and let the app take care of the timing e.g. student has a lesson at 9am to 10am in room kQ232, the room will be assigned a beacon and the app will do something if they get the beacon id in-between that time. 
Before I was thinking that the teacher would carry the beacon around with them and when they enter a room there teaching in, they will turn it on using the app and log in credentials to allow students to get attendance for that class.